# From a 2D array, how to create groups (i.e. arrays) of inner arrays which have the same value for a particular field?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have the following array:

```
fruits = [
  0 => ["color"=>"red", "name"=>"apple"],
  1 => ["color"=>"red", "name"=>"tomato"],
  2 => ["color"=>"green", "name"=>"kiwi"],
  3 => ["color"=>"red", "name"=>"carrot"],
  4 => ["color"=>"yellow", "name"=>"banana"],
  5 => ["color"=>"yellow", "name"=>"mango"],
];
```

And I need to get it into the following form:

```
fruits = [
  0 => [
    0 => ["color"=>"red", "name"=>"apple"],
    1 => ["color"=>"red", "name"=>"tomato"],
    2 => ["color"=>"red", "name"=>"carrot"]
  ], 
  1 => [
    0 => ["color"=>"yellow", "name"=>"banana"],
    1 => ["color"=>"yellow", "name"=>"mango"],
  ],
  2 => [
    0 => ["color"=>"green", "name"=>"kiwi"],
  ]
];
```

That is I need to group on the basis of color of the fruit.

I tried but somehow I can not get it correct.

Comment: Where is your code or attempt to solve the problem on your own? What have you tried so far? Please edit your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to loop the colors by extracting names and colors to seperate flat arrays.
This way you only loop the count of unique colors (in this case three times).
Then you do the matching with array_intersect.

```
$colors = array_column($fruits, "color");
$names = array_column($fruits, "name");
foreach(array_unique($colors) as $color) $new[$color] = array_intersect_key($names, array_intersect($colors, [$color]));

var_dump($new);
```

https://3v4l.org/5pODc

Answer (score 2):

An associative array would be simple :

```
$sortedFruits = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < count($fruits); $i++) {
  if(!$sortedFruits[$fruits[$i]['color']]) { $sortedFruits[$fruits[$i]['color']] = array(); }
  array_push($sortedFruits[$fruits[$i]['color']], $fruits[$i]);
}
print_r($sortedFruits['red']);
```

Answer (score -1):

You're overcomplicating the resulting array, I would suggest to replace first level key with color name and just go with names in each of them.

Building a code logic for your example will be way to big and it doesn't need to be.